# Universal Login Authorization in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I need a help on login authorization. When I use a direct link of one of my web page without providing credentials (without logging in) then I need to be redirected to the login page for proper login with login credentials. How can I go about this with JSP?

Comment: Universal Login Authorization , are you talking about single sign on.

Comment: @suresh: ni my requirement is when i use a direct link of a web page without login that should be redirected to login page for credentials

Answer (score 2):

- Create a [filter](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html)
- Check for some session attribute . if present consider logged in user , otherwise `response.sendRedirect("url to login page");`

Comment: @joshi: thanks for responding i dont know how to do that if u dont mind can u send me the code please

Comment: can you please check the link of filter given

Comment: Hehe, "pls send teh codez". A real one! :) I just had to vote that up. :)