# Verifying Cookies in JSP using JSTL

Tags: java, jsp, cookies, jstl

I'm trying to figure out how cookies can be used to prevent a hacker from typing in a URL to an internal part of a java web application that shouldn't be accessible unless the user is logged in.

For example, I'd like to prevent a hacker from typing in http://domain.com/myapp/listtable.jsp and be able to view the table without logging in.

I have a servlet which stores a list of all cookies it has handed out to clients. I'm struggling to understand what the JSP/JSTL code would look like to examine the cookies in the request and compare it to what the server has stored.

Something like:

```
    <c:forEach items="${cookie}" var="currentCookie">  

        <!-- Compare each incoming cookie with the cookies kept in the servlet,
             if there's not a match then redirect to the login page. Otherwise,
             show the contents of the page below --> 

    </c:forEach>  

<html>

    --- main page HTML here
```

Can anyone give me some advice on how to do this?

Comment: This is the job of a servlet, not a JSP

Comment: Yes but if the URL of the jsp is typed in directly in the client browser, the servlet doesn't run before the JSP does, correct?

Comment: JSPs should not be directly visible to the browser, they should be hidden inside `WEB-INF`, and accessed via servlets. That's basic good design for java webapps.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info to learn about servlet filters. It even contains a hello world filter which does exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be the Job of [`Filter`](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html) not of view

- Configure a `Filter` to check for your protected resources
- Check if user's session has some value that logically makes him logged in.
- if not redirect user to login view

**See Also**

- [universal-login-authorization-in-jsp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5387345/universal-login-authorization-in-jsp)
- [why-business-logic-should-be-moved-out-of-jsp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818101/why-business-logic-should-be-moved-out-of-jsp)

Comment: @Elite: Yes, but @Jigar had the good sense to post it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I would personally add my JSP or any presentation content (that you deem protected) under the `WEB-INF` folder and map it accordingly to your controller. That way, the servlet container will hide it from external viewing.

Answer (score 0):

Even it's not the correct way to do it... in fact you can do something like that.

Try this:

```
    <c:forEach items="${cookie}" var="currentCookie">  

            <!-- Compare each incoming cookie with the cookies kept in the servlet,
                 if there's not a match then redirect to the login page. Otherwise,
                 show the contents of the page below --> 


            ${currentCookie.value.name} - ${currentCookie.value.value}<br/>

            <c:if test="${currentCookie.value.name=='JSESSIONID'}">
                Your Session is ${currentCookie.value.value}
            </c:if> 


    </c:forEach>
```

Comment: Replace `currentCookie.value` by `currentCookie` and it'll be valid.