# Serlvet Login Implementation

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, authentication

I have an application which has one main servlet MainServlet.java and it intercepts all http request ( url-pattern is /* ). This application is unsecured. Now I want to implement login functionality such as

1. Non-authenticated user will be directed to login form http:/localhost:8080/app/login
2. Login form target http:/localhost:8080/app/loginAuth

Any Idea How to go about it?

Answer (score 0):

Add a `Filter` for that it is [better suited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5387345/universal-login-authorization-in-jsp)

Comment: how should i take care of servlet mapping MainServlet => /* ( url pattern ) ?

Comment: Map your Authentication Filter to `/*`

Answer (score 0):

Look at http://www.developer.com/security/article.php/3467801/Securing-J2EE-Applications-with-a-Servlet-Filter.htm